# How can I jump to function definitions using VS Code in SSH remote development

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, vscode-remote

Okay I am new to Embedded Linux development.
Right now, I am trying to setup the development environment as efficiently as possible.

I have a python code running on a lightweight Linux based device, that is located remotely

So far I was able to setup my VS Code on my Windows system, in such a way that I can edit the files directly on the remote Linux device.
I followed the instructions below

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh-tutorial

Now that I am able to edit my files directly, I face only one obstacle.
I find it hard to traverse to a function/method definition.

In my windows system, I could just **Ctrl+LeftClick** on a method/function, and it would take me there.

But here when I opened VS Code with the terminal running remotely, I have to do a Ctrl+F and search in the VS Code editor, which is like working on a notepad.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

On my main windows system, I am able to jump to method definitions quickly by **Ctrl+LefClick**-ing them.

Hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: Has the Python extension been installed on the remote server?

Comment: This should usually work, even with remote development. Have you [selected the Python interpreter on the Linux device](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) in VS code?

Comment: Doing both of the above solved my problem. It took a minute for it to apply it. Also it takes a few seconds for the edit-cursor to jump to each method definition. I am guessing that is to do with the VPN speed. I didn't know we have to install interpreter and extension for each ssh session. My mind was wrapped around the understanding that python is a format, already known by VS Code. Thank you so much for the input.

Comment: @carlfriedrich How do I accept this as an answer on stack?

Comment: @Arjee Jacob Jacob: I'll post this as an answer, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Python extension on the remote server and [select the Python interpreter on the Linux device](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) in VS code:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the command `Python: Select Interpreter`.

[image: select interpreter]